# iOS: Why does the timer (and performSelector) trigger the selected method immediately?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've tried to use both:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(enableGestures)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
```

and

```
[self performSelector:@selector(enableGestures) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

to trigger the enableGestures method, however in both versions it is triggered twice! (First when the timer starts and second after 2 seconds). Same thing with the second snippet. Why ?

thanks

Comment: That makes no sense. There is no way `performSelector...afterDelay` would trigger immediately. You might need to show some of the surrounding code.

Comment: What are you doing in `enableGestures`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` message should have this signature:

```
- (void)enableGestures:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

I wrote a little test code, and without a proper signature for the selector, the selector is sometimes called immediately, and then again when the timer finishes. When I changed it to a proper signature, the selector was first called after the appropriate delay. I never saw this problem with a properly formatted signature, and about half the time saw this problem with the improper signature.

I tried the second version, and it worked correctly every time.

If this is happening consistently with both versions of timing code, something else somewhere in the code is sending the `enableGestures` message.